# Is using Application context kind of God object antipatern

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-context

I find that using application class to store some shared variables or to get to things like  PACKAGE_NAME or OS version via methods quite useful. This is because in this way you can get to this data from any component in your app and you can store objects that exist while your app is loaded, thus you avoiding some of GC and lifecycle problems. Although useful if used sparingly this seems like an antipattern to me. Because basically application class is doing too much.

What I would like to know is what are your thoughts about this and should this approach be discouraged in favour of Persistent headless Fragment or some other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the application object is a god object and therefore an anti pattern.

However, as with all patterns there are pros and cons.

Pros

1. Quick to use the application object as a god object

Cons:

1. Difficult to effectively manage the lifetime of data in the application object since the application object is bound to the lifetime of your application
2. Difficult to properly unit test an Android activity or fragment which is heavily coupled to the application object
3. If you're using the application object to store information that is specific to one or two screens, eventually the object will become a hodgepodge of what is effectively unrelated information, and therefore difficult to manaage